# How do you write an inject argument with a non-integer number in Anylogic

Tags: integer, double, anylogic, inject

I am trying to write code for my Anylogic discrete events model which injects a specific number of agents, and then after 4 weeks, this injected number of agents is conditional on other numbers of agents in the model (circled in red on the screenshot). One of the sources of agents that I want to account for is a Double (it is on a slider), and the inject call will not accept it, it only wants int values.

```
weeklyLeavingNursing = 0;

if (time()<4) {

    enterHerd.inject(10);

}
 
else {

    enterHerd.inject(10 - (slider.getValue() + weeklyLeavingOpen + weeklyLeavingNursing));

}
```

Is there a way to write the code with both int and Double values?
Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.
[image: Image of the coding and the Anykogic error]
[image: Image of the full model and the 3 areas where agents enter the Source]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the following function:

```
getIntValue()
```

[image]